# Regex get subfolder name from URL after domain extension

Tags: regex

i'm new to regex, so I want to write a **regExp** to identify a special subfolder path directly after the `tld` top level domain extension.

> http://sub.domain.tld**/foo**/bar

How to do it?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read [ask], take a [tour]. Questions should provide a [mcve] of what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you're searching for a parent folder which itself is in the root directory, try like `/\.tld\/([^/]+)\//`

```js
const str = "http://sub.domain.tld/foo/bar";

console.log(str.match(/\.tld\/([^/]+)\//)[1])
```

- `\.tld\/` preceded by *.tld/*
- `([^/]+)` capture everything that is not a / ...
- `\/` ...till the first /

Comment: I'd consider a `?` at the end in case the `/foo` was the end of the url.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `tld` can be any of the usual - not literally `tld`, try

```
\.\w*\/([^\/\s]*)  // group 1 will have your desired folder
```

[regex101 demo with test cases](https://regex101.com/r/sdZiPp/1)